# Unable to read Unicode characters from Oracle variable

Tags: oracle, unicode

I'm using an Oracle database that is not *globally* set up for Unicode -- but I have been able to work with Unicode characters as needed using the `NVARCHAR2` data type in columns where it is needed.

This has worked fine for data stored in the database -- but my current use case is for a temporary variable. For the purposes of the question, the following illustrates my problem:

```
VAR TEST NVARCHAR2(50);
DEFINE TEST = 'This string contains “Unicode” characters';

SELECT '&&TEST' AS TEST
FROM DUAL;
```

I would expect this output to be:

```
This string contains “Unicode” characters
```

But instead it is:

```
This string contains ¿Unicode¿ characters
```

Is this failure because of the global database settings? If so, is there a workaround without changing those settings?

(I tested some of the solutions I found in other questions, such as experimenting with `CAST` and `TO_NCHAR`, and also saving the script on a page explicitly coded for UTF-8 -- but none of those strategies was successful. I think the fact that I am using a local variable distinguishes this from existing questions.)

## Follow-up to Comments

**laubster** asked for the output from:

```
SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'
```

That output is `WE8ISO8859P15`.

**Alex Poole** asked about the client and character settings.

The client is SQL Developer. OS is Windows 10. I'm not entirely sure where to look for client character settings -- but perhaps the answer is the same as the result from **laubster**'s query: `WE8ISO8859P15`.

In any event, that may be a moot point. `The N'text'` strategy (which I'd never heard of before) worked.

I think I've got what I need. It doesn't look like **Alex Poole** is hurting for points -- but if he* wants to post that as an answer, I'll certainly upvote and mark as correct.

* I'm assuming "he" based on the avatar. Apologies if I'm mistaken.

Comment: (Your bind variable declaration is a red herring: you're not using it at all, and thus dealing only in the realm of regular VARCHAR2.)  Edit your question to add your NLS_LANG setting from the client side, and the output from `SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'`.

Comment: Which client is this, and what are the OS and client character settings? What happens if you use [the `n'text'` version of a text literal](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218)? (Not sure if `var` even supports that, but you would need it in the query anyway I think.)

Comment: Question has been edited in follow-up to the comments above.

Comment: When you use `NVARCHAR2` then `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` applies - not `NLS_CHARACTERSET`

Comment: @laubster, SQL Developer is Java based which does not use `NLS_LANG` settings, see [Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/global.htm#JJDBC28643)

Comment: @JoeDeRose - I don't have an environment where I can replicate what you're seeing or test my suggestion; everything I've tried to fake it has failed. If you got it working please feel free to add an answer explaining what you had to do. (In addition to what you've already added, including your Oracle and SQL Developer versions, and your `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` value, might be helpful for future visitors. And - maybe - the encoding setting for SQL Developer, from Tools->Preferences->Environment->Encoding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

Okay, based on the information provided by **Alex Poole**, the key to making this work is the [`N'text'` notation for a text literal](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00217). Going back to the example in my question above:

```
VAR TEST VARCHAR2(50);
DEFINE TEST = 'This string contains “Unicode” characters';

SELECT '&&TEST' AS TEST
FROM DUAL;
```

Gives the result:

```
This string contains ¿Unicode¿ characters
```

## Solution

But the `N'text'` strategy:

```
SELECT N'&&TEST' AS TEST
FROM DUAL;
```

Gives the expected result:

```
This string contains “Unicode” characters
```

In my real-world example, this functionality was wrapped in a `CASE` statement, which added a little more complexity. If I used the `N'text'` notation only in the line where Unicode characters were expected, it triggered error "ORA-12704: character set mismatch". to make it work, I had to add the `N` in front of the non-Unicode text in the `ELSE` line as well:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN 1 = 1 THEN N'&&TEST'
    ELSE N'(Some other output)'
  END AS TEST_OUTPUT
FROM DUAL;
```

## Settings Information

In case it is helpful to others in a similar situation, here are the relevant settings that **Alex Poole** suggested I provide:

- Oracle version: **11g (11.2.0.4.0) - 64 bit**
- `NLS_CHARACTERSET`: **WE8ISO8859P15**
- `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`: **AL16UTF16**
- SQL Developer version: **4.1.5.21**
- SQL Developer Encoding: **UTF-8**